# How to call methods during run time using java instrumentation

Tags: java, instrumentation

I'm completely new to this instrumentation concept. I have a custom jar file which has lot of methods. Lets assume for now i have start and stop method. Inorder to collect the start and stop metrics i need to call those methods after every click . Instead of doing that is there a way to instrument this. I want this methods to be called for all clickable elements dynamically before and after during runtime. Any advise on this would be great. Thanks in advance. Please find the sample code.

**Custom Methods:**

```
  Public void start (){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void stop{
    long finish= System.currentTimeMillis();
     long totalTime = finish - start;
    }
```

**Sample Code:**

```
start();
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendkeys("@@@");
stop();

start();
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendkeys("@@@");
stop();

start();
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
stop();
```

Comment: What You need is rather some AOP solution rather then instrumentation. If You are using any kind of IoC container (e.g. Spring, Guice, CDI/EJB) You can implement an interceptor to cover this use case. I can give You more information If You provide more details about Your code or frameworks You are using if any.

Comment: I'm using selenium webdriver to launch a browser and trying to calculate the response time. Not using any framework. Its a simple Selenium script . Any advise on how to implement instrumentation for this sample code would be great.

Comment: I see, so yes code instrumentation  would be a fitting solution, You can check for example ByteBuddy. I will try to prepare some example for You when i will have some more time.

Comment: There is also an option to use EventListeners in Selenium. Here is a good example http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/.

Comment: Event Listeners would be a good solution for Selenium Webdrivers. Could you please share a sample for code instrumentation. that would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The instrumentation sample turns out a little tricky, so I would stick with listeners for "real world" code. But i think i will manage to present some basic example using ByteBuddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example instrumentation solution using ByteBuddy, although as I mentioned in comments under this question it's probably not a best approach to solve this.

For this simple example the code only covers a case where invocations on WebDriver and WebElement are chained e.g.:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("logout")).click();
```

Something like below fragment will not work without additional coding:

```
WebElement element1 = findElement(By.name("login"));
WebElement element2 = findElement(By.name("logout"));
element2.click();
element1.click();
```

Instrumentation code:

```
public class ByteBuddyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    

        ByteBuddyAgent.install();

        new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(RemoteWebDriver.class)
            .visit(Advice.to(WebDriverAdvice.class).on(named("findElement").and(takesArguments(1))))
            .make()
            .load(ByteBuddyTest2.class.getClassLoader(),
                  ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

        new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(RemoteWebElement.class)
            .visit(Advice.to(WebElementAdvice.class).on(named("click")))
            .make()
            .load(ByteBuddyTest2.class.getClassLoader(),
                  ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.get("<some webpage>");

        driver.findElement(By.id("<some_id>")).click();
    }

    public static class WebDriverAdvice {    
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void enter(@Advice.Origin String method) {
            System.out.printf("Driver Method Enter: %s\n", method);
            Times.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    public static class WebElementAdvice {
        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        public static void exit(@Advice.Origin String method, @Advice.This Object target) {
            System.out.printf("Element Method Exit: %s\n", method);
            System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - Times.start));
        }
    }

    public static class Times {
        public static long start = 0L;
    }
}
```

**Example using WebDriverEventListener**

```
public class WebDriverEventListenerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        eventDriver.register(new EventHandler());

        eventDriver.get("<some webpage>");
        eventDriver.findElement(By.id("<some id>")).click();
        eventDriver.findElement(By.id("<some id>")).click();
    }

    public static class EventHandler extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener {

        @Override public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
            System.out.printf("Driver Find By: %s\n", by);
            Times.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        @Override public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
            System.out.printf("Element Method Exit: %s\n", element);
            System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - Times.start));
        }
    }

    public static class Times {
        public static long start = 0L;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing wonderful example. Is android driver compatible with appium eventListener. Kindly share any sample code that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot answer about android compatibility - i do not have any android knowledge. I added simple example using selenium WebDriverEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to benchmark code.  If so, I suggest using a benchmarking framework, such as [Google Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper), which helps instrument code while nominally impacting the actual performance of the code, and it also helps account for JIT compiling, etc., which may alter the execution time of your method as code is executed repeatedly.